# Converting an existing Java project to Maven in vscode

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

I have this old Java project without anything, I want to use maven with it because some dependencies are missing and I can't find the libs.
Can someone tell me how to convert that project to maven `WITH VSCODE`.

Comment: First make it work as-is then convert.  No magic can help you.

Comment: Since the Java language support of VSCode is Eclipse, converting the project to a Maven project should be possible with Eclipse in order to be able to edit the converted project with both Eclipse and VSCode: in Eclipse do _File > Open Projects from File System..._ and then right-click the project folder and choose _Configure > Convert to Maven Project_.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen In Eclipse this magic is called _Smart Import_.

Comment: @howlger This does not locate the original dependencies.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Of course it does.

Comment: @howlger Did a quick experiment with an old version of a legacy project in 2021-12.  Smart Import still resulted in lots of `Project 'X' is missing required library: 'U:/projects/X/lib/jdom.jar'` and Quick-Fix did not help locating the correct jar file on the net (which was the magic I talked about).   What Eclipse functionality have I missed?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen _Smart Import_.

Comment: @howlger I did use the “import existing git repository (with smart imports)”.  Should I have used another?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen _“import existing git repository (with smart imports)”_?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some steps:

1. Tell VS Code to [use Maven](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-build).
2. Add a [pom.xml](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) to your project to spell out the dependencies.
3. Ask Maven to download the dependencies to your local .m2 repository.
4. Use the [Maven lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) to compile/test/package your code.

You'll have no problem as long as all the JARs you need are in Maven Central.  If some of them were internal to your organization you'll have to find them and pull them from a private repo or add them to your local .m2.

If this is an old Java project you might want to think about updating.  Check the JARs for security vulnerabilities and upgrade them if you can.  Hopefully there will be a good Junit suite to prove that upgrades didn't break your code.

One last suggestion: Try to compile and run it on a LTS version of the JDK - 11 or 17.  Don't continue with JDK 8 - it's past the end of its support life.

This is easy in IntelliJ.  I'd prefer it to VS Code.

Comment: “Spell out the dependencies” - isn’t this where help is needed?

Comment: I don’t think so.  Method is more important here.

Comment: i 'Asked maven to download the dependencies'. it's not listening.   i feel this answer should be more in depth for new users...what exactly does 'ask' mean in context of vscode? is there a maven explorer, is there a command like (pip install)?

Comment: 'Ask' means 'create a pom.xml for your project with all the dependencies inside'.   Maven is built into IntelliJ.  The Maven command line equivalent is "mvn" command.  I expect that somebody will go and read about Maven without me having to recreate all its documentation here.